# How to update the value of particular tag of XML file using shell script

Tags: bash, shell

How I pass the arguments to `sed` command to replace a particular string . I want to replace 8080 with some different port like `8181` or `8282`.

```
grep -rl 8080 /tmp/standalone.xml | xargs sed -i 's/8080/8181/g'
```

Comment: 8181 is dynamic value.                                                                                  port="$1"                                                                                                 grep -rl 8080 /tmp/standalone.xml | xargs sed -i 's/8080/"$port"/g'                       It will replace 8080 with "$port" not with the inputs

Comment: Just use double quotes: `sed "s/8080/$port/g"`, this way the `$port` will be expanded to its actual value.

Comment: This is one where you have the correct tool for the job, and the question is "How do I use it?". Basic substitution is covered in a cursory fashion in the man page, but there are literally 100's of good `sed` tutorials/examples on the web. This is a valid question, but it is borderline between getting dinged for not doing due-diligence before asking the question. No downvotes, but be aware, stackoverflow, as a programming site, really encourages you to look before you ask. Just guidance for the future -- Welcome to SO

Comment: Is `/tmp/standalone.xml` a folder?

Comment: No no luck.. name="http" port=""$port""

Comment: Given that this is XML, you should consider using XSLT, rather than `sed`/`grep`.

Comment: Or use `xmlstarlet`, an
 xml editor

Answer (score 1):

You want to use double quotes instead of single as variables can then be expanded, something like:

```
 grep -rl 8080 /tmp/standalone.xml | xargs sed -i "s/8080/$port/g"
```

Comment: port=""$port"" this was coming instead of 8181 or 8222

Comment: What exact command are you running, @SANU ? It looks like you are using extra double quotes, while Paul's code should be more than enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can sed directly

```
sed -i "s/$oldValue/$newValue/g" /tmp/standalone.xml
```

or

```
sed -i "s/8080/8181/g" /tmp/standalone.xml
```